# How do I export an MFC DLL project settings to be imported as a new MFC DLL project in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, import, mfc, visual-studio-2019, project

I don't want a property file.  I have a set of Extension DLLs I am porting from old VS that are all MFC DLLs into a bunch of individual VS 2019 MFC extension DLL projects.  I've done the first one, and I just need to use that project's properties (all of them) as a template (sans files) for each of the others.

Basically, a copy of the .vcxproj file without the files sections but with new project GUIDs.

Property Manager just wants to define a container .props file for specific properties that are then merged into the project settings at load time (every load).  I just need a one time export, then import that into each "new" MFC project at creation - one time (for each), not every time as a property file.

Is my best bet just make a copy of the .vcxproj file, generate new guids then manually edit each .vcxproj file for each new project???

Comment: I was able to "merge" a template of my .vcxproj file with the VS generated .vcxproj via WinMerge.  I remembered to create the new one as an MFC Extension DLL, the rest of the settings were easily merged in from the template, keeping the new project's .def file name and similar entries.  Things like the two .props files (for common lib, inc paths etc.) along with configuration options (32 bit x86 only, debug vs. release settings, no x64), kept the original stdafx vs pch precompiled header/file names, etc. etc. etc).

Comment: Obviously, if there is a "better" way to do this (vs. WinMerge), please let me know.  Now I just need to add the specific .cpp files for that DLL and get them to build (the "easy" part - NOT!).  Then repeat this process for 25+ more DLLs.